# Is it possible to control the frequency of light?

Tags: light, optoelectronics

I mean, controlling directly in the source, not filtering the light or arranging density of the medium.  For example, brightness can be controlled by current or voltage directly. However, when I came to frequency, I could not find a source-controlled "frequency control technique".

Thanks to comments another question is evolved: Is it possible to control the movement of electrons between the energy levels?

Comment: What does it mean "source" for you? If you have two different color laser emitters bundled together, and have a switch to select between them - does it count as controlling the frequency at the source?

Comment: Anyway, a really quick google search revealed something called [Tunable Laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunable_laser)

Comment: I saw it. It uses prisms to control frequency in other words it changes medium. I mean by source current, voltage, or heat anything that is used in energy conversion. Something --> Light

Comment: A poly-chromatic acoustic optic modulator (PCAOM) can be used to select specific colors of light from a white laser input.

Comment: A stove element changes from deep-red (low heat) to orange (high heat). Crude, and not very frequency-coherent...but meets your wavelength-variable requirement.

Comment: @glen_geek I would guess it has the same wavelength compositions though, but with different intensities depending on the temperature.

Comment: @Ekrem_Abi Do you know how light is "created" ? It is "created" by electrons jumping between energy levels. The energy levels are fixed in a specific material. So there is no way to change the frequencies in the "source". Only to combine different "sources".

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes, many wavelength components, but the peak wavelength and average wavelength does shift, and noticeable to our eye.

Comment: Oh well. You can use gravity for gravitational redshift :P Again, not in the source, though.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks, I edited the question. So, in that case, is it possible to control the movement of electrons between energy levels?

Comment: @JYelton A true white laser is kind of hard to come by, no?

Comment: We are controlling them in a sense that we can stimulate their "jumps" between the levels. But we can't move the energy levels around.

Comment: @JohnD Yes; PCAOMs were used in older laser projectors where two or more beams are first combined to achieve white (like HeNe + Argon). I just added the comment as a possible thing for the OP to look into, in case it would be applicable.

Comment: Good old incandescent lamps, and any other black-body radiator, emit different wavelengths depending on their temperature, which in turn depends on voltage, current and/or duty cycle. It’s not a single wavelength though, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/357035/93082

Comment: Tunable lasers exist that change wavelength at which the laser has gain rather than filtering the output. Some are even electronically actuated.

Comment: @user1850479 is right.  Many of them work by using a prism or grating such that the cavity is only aligned for one wavelength, thus all other wavelengths have a gain <<1; the actual gain medium works over a wide range of wavelengths (e.g. dye lasers)

Answer (score 12):

Of course you can.

1. [Tunable lasers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunable_laser) are a thing; you can modulate different aspects of the light generation process in different types of lasers.
2. You can excite a laser diode with a sinusoidal signal, which inherently means you've built a frequency synthesizer. That sinsusoidal signal can be electronically generated. Modulating laser diodes is commonly done in fiberoptical communication, and since electronic speeds limit modulation frequencies to a couple hundred gigahertz.
3. Same goes for modulating a Mach-Zehnder modulator with harmonic oscillations. All the remarks given to sinusoidal excitation apply here, too.
4. using a frequency comb and a nonlinear medium, you can generate a large set of intermodulation products; depending on how you control the comb, you can thus select from a grid of wavelengths.

Comment: Aren't 2 and 3 not what the OP is (seemingly) asking? These are about modulating a signal on top of a monochromatic carrier wavelength, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @EugeneSh. my understanding is that OP thinks that modulating amplitude is something different than what you do when modulating frequency, where in reality modulation with a harmonic signal is always a frequency shift.

Comment: My understanding that by "frequency" the OP meant "color"

Comment: The visible spectrum is somewhere in the range of 400 THz wide, so 1 and 4 should cover visible color changes. 2 and 3 can effect color changes, but the question is whether it's visible.

Comment: For what it is worth, you need a pretty decent laser in order to resolve the modulation sidebands. Most laser diodes have linewidths of about a nanometer or so.

Comment: @polwel definitely, but if the question is "change the wavelength", then it's basically how much the center of gravity of the PSD shifts

Comment: One additional note: the tunable lasers article on Wikipedia is pretty outdated (it says things like "as of December 2008") and MEMS VCSEL / VECSEL are now much more capable and available technologies than the article makes obvious.

Comment: @Polynomial generally, I think it's not a great article and could be structurally overhauled.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm not sure that I can do the topic justice, otherwise I'd fix it myself. But if you end up taking a crack at a rewrite, let me know and I'll happily run a QA pass over it.

Comment: @Polynomial I'm *sure* I can't. It's just not well-structured :(

Answer (score 8):

> I mean, controlling directly in the source, not filtering the light or arranging density of the medium.

This is essentially what a tunable laser does.  Internally a laser is an excited piece of matter that has optical gain between two mirrors.  That gain is highest at some (usually very small) number of wavelengths, so the laser output is nearly monochromatic.  Tunable lasers further include a mechanism to move where that gain maximum is.  RP Photonics has an article article on the many, many ways this can be done:

https://www.rp-photonics.com/wavelength_tuning.html

Rather than repeat it here, I will give one simple example.  Many laser diodes can be thermally tuned, where you heat or cool them (possibly by driving more or less current into the diode) to change the wavelength they emit.  This effect has several causes, including changes in the band structure of semiconductor from temperature/current as well as changes in refractive index due to thermal expansion of the material.

> Thanks to comments another question is evolved: Is it possible to control the movement of electrons between the energy levels?

The actual comment that caused you to change your question is incorrect.  The band structure of a material isn't completely fixed (see temperature/current tuning), you can emit wavelengths of light that do not correspond to a energy levels in a material, and you also don't necessarily need to change energy levels in order to change the wavelengths that are emitted.  Many materials are available in which the band structure spans to tens or hundreds of nanometers worth of energy levels. For example, the Ti:S laser cavity can emit light at all wavelengths from about 680nm to more than 1100nm, a range of more than 400nm.  Tunable light sources using a Ti:S crystal can emit any (or all) of these wavelengths.

Then there are devices like [parametric oscillators](https://www.rp-photonics.com/optical_parametric_oscillators.html).  Since they do not depend on the energy levels of a material to generate new photons, a single device can tune between thousands of nanometers worth of wavelengths, sometimes covering the UV, VIS an NIR.

So in summary, it is absolutely possible to control the frequency/wavelength of light with the right equipment.

Answer (score 3):

LEDs temperature-tune quite nicely, but it take liquid nitrogen to get a few ten of nanometres.  I just tried one that's amber at room temperature but greenish-yellow at 77 K.  They also get much brighter for constant current as you reduce the temperature, while the forward voltage drop increases dramatically.  This changing brightness and my phone not allowing me to disable auto-exposure is why my attempt to film it for you failed miserably.

Little laser diodes show less shift.  I had a red laser-pointer type diode here, and in LN it got brighter, then dimmer as it cooled, without appreciably changing colour

Answer (score 2):

Use an incandescent bulb with a dimmer switch, the temperature of the emitter will change as you dim, and the blackbody curve will change accordingly. This of course only applies if you don't want a monochromatic or coherent source.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking about is just an antenna...but for optical frequencies rather than radio. They are called "optical antennas" and are still in development since visible light has very short wavelength which means very short antennas which presents manufacturing difficulties (they are nanoscale). On top of that the drive signals required are also very high frequency which also makes things tricky.

Answer (score 1):

"the frequency of light" is a well-defined quantity
only for a monochromatic source.

Good monochromatic visible-light sources are spectrum lines, and
either Stark effect (electric field) or Zeeman effect
(magnetic field) can change them.   It just isn't
very sensitive, give small modulation compared to typical line widths.

Various dodges, however, can get better effects;
notably, photoacoustic gratings can be combined
with laser-gain amplifiers to make tuned sources.

Easiest, though, is to use two LEDs of different colors, and only turn one on.

Comment: You've got Zeeman and Stark mixed up.

Comment: @polwel- yeah, I goofed; fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of question someone asks when the do not understand homo-lumo transistion in molecular orbit theory and band gaps in semiconductor materials allow electrons to be excited and fall back to ground states to create emissions.

Once those phenomena are understood, the question becomes clear that cleaver use of light filtering and solicitation with mirrors and laser tuning must be used to select a specific wavelength from a tail on a Gaussian emission curve from the aforementioned emission mechanisms.

So, if you don't like those techniques and they are all disqualified by your criteria, the only possible answer thst accounts for all of your criteria is, no.  No, light color cannot be tuned at the source according to your criteria.